# Как "нащупать дно" (отследить момент касания конца страницы) при скроллинге на мобильном устройстве?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, мобильная-разработка

Подобная конструкция работает только для стационарной версии:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        ...
```

Моб. устройства просто не понимают, что ты достиг конца страницы при скроллинге...
Задумка проста: нужно при скроллинге до низа страницы подгружать контент на манер бесконечной подгрузки контента.

Каким образом можно "словить" этот момент?

Answer (score 3):

Запускал локальный сервер с помощью Gulp, на компе брузер Chrome работает, на мобилке браузер Safari на Iphone7 работает.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    if ($('html, body').scrollTop()+$(window).height() == document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
        $('body').append('<p style="color: green">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>')
    }
});
```

```css
p{
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim voluptate ex unde. Ex tenetur veniam dolores enim, tempore deserunt provident. Suscipit non quaerat blanditiis impedit, voluptatibus mollitia odio voluptates sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, qui ratione vel ullam saepe odio, eveniet sapiente quas libero cum ipsa, minus a magni. Atque, vitae ipsum nihil facilis earum.</p>
```

Comment: Кстати я тут подумал, на Iphone при прокрутке вниз шторка внизу браузера прячется думаю благодаря этому и достигается это самое "дно". В других телефонах не знаю как это происходит. Логичнее сделать по моему мнению, отнять около 100px от высоты документа, и тогда условие будет выполнятся, и контент будет заранее подгружатьсья. Мое личное субъективное мнение.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var crntHeight = $(this).children("#place").height();
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= (crntHeight - $(this).height()-100)){
... {ajax} ...
```

Примерно такая конструкция работает на мобильном. Правда не идеально.
Может быть есть у кого-то наработки?